# Passing params to my components in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm customizing a datepicker in angular because I need to use it throughout the whole app. Is there a way to do this by passing params from component's definition. I mean e.g.:

Taking into account that my component's tag is `<app-date-picker></app-date-picker>`, whose code inside is very simple:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Date issued" disabled>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

So, I need to define my component like this `<app-date-picker [inputDisabled]="false"></app-date-picker>` for the input to be disabled for some instances, or like this `<app-date-picker [inputDisabled]="true"></app-date-picker>` for the input to be enabled.

Is this possible? What's the way to do it?

Comment: it's angular (typescript) not angulaJjs, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you defined is a perfect way !!

```
<app-date-picker [inputDisabled]="false"></app-date-picker>
```

In DatePickerComponent you need to take the input using `@Input`

In date-picker.component.ts

```
export class DatePickerComponent {
    @Input() inputDisabled: boolean;
}
```

In date-picker.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Date issued" [disabled]="inputDisabled">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks LALI KANTA for your rapid answer. I just change my code by yours and the component did what I wanted.

Comment: Nice to hear that ..  If it helps , please accept the answer